# How to build a framework compatible with Simulator and iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I tried to make separate builds for iOS and Simulator and then combine them into a single framework, but lipo command fails.

1. Here is how I build a framework for iOS
   `xcodebuild -project FrameworkiOS.xcodeproj -target FrameworkiOS -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator clean build`
2. Here is how I build a framework for a simulator
   `xcodebuild -project FrameworkiOS.xcodeproj -target FrameworkiOS -configuration Release -sdk iphones clean build`
3. Then I try to use lipo command
   lipo -create "FrameworkiOS.framework/FrameworkiOS" "FrameworkSimulator.framework/FrameworkiOS" -output Framework.framework

But lipo command fails with the error:
fatal error: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: FrameworkiOS.framework/FrameworkiOS and FrameworkSimulator.framework/FrameworkiOS have the same architectures (arm64) and can't be in the same fat output file`

I am using MacBook with M1 chip.

How can I create a framework and use it for both iOS devices and Simulators?

Answer (score 0):

Include the framework for the simulator and the framework for the iOS Device in a single XCFramework.

Use XCFramework instead of the fat library so you can provide multi-architecture support in future(tvOS, macOS).